# pygame key detect not detecting keypresses

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to get pygame to detect my keypresses and change the background to a random color, but every time press the selected key, nothing changes. the background color of the window stays the same.

```
import pygame
import random

running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
detect=True
keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
while detect:
  pygame.event.pump()
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if keys[pygame.K_0]:
    screen.fill((random.randint(0, 255)), (random.randint(0, 255)), (random.randint(0, 255)))
    pygame.display.update()
  if keys[pygame.K_1]:
    screen.fill((random.randint(0, 255)), (random.randint(0, 255)), (random.randint(0, 255)))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: what is screen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the program never reaches the second half of your code.

The first `while True` statment, which does nothing to the screen, but wait for the user to close the window runs all the time - the code that shoudl detect key presses is only executed upon receiving a `pygame.QUIT` event (and then the window closes).

The way programs work,  they run a single loop, wit all statements in it - the `while` loops won't run in parallel - you have to do:

```py
import pygame
import random

running = True

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

while running:
    pygame.event.pump()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_0]:
        screen.fill((random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
        pygame.display.update()
    if keys[pygame.K_1]:
        screen.fill((random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(30)

pygame.quit()
```

(Also note the call to "pygame.time.delay", otherwise the while loop will run using all CPU resources, trying to fetch events much quicker than they could arrive, and doing nothing with that - your simple example would burn at 100% CPU)